# simplexml_import_dom - как получить CDATA

Tags: xmlreader

При наличии CDATA в тегах выводится пустота. Подскажите, как добавить возможность чтения данного тега  ?

```
function openXML($file_name,$key,$limit=0){

$z = new XMLReader;

$z->open($file_name);
$doc = new DOMDocument;

$result = array();



while ($z->read() && $z->name !== $key);

    
$i = 0;
while ($z->name === $key)
{
    
    $fdfsd = @$z->expand();
    
    if(!$fdfsd){
        $result='error_end_tag';
        break;
    }
    
        
    
    $df = $doc->importNode($fdfsd, true);
    $node = simplexml_import_dom($df);      
    

    
    $i++;
    $z->next($key);
    
    $result[]=$node;
    
    if($limit>0 && $i==$limit)
        break;
    

}


return $result;
```

}